# How to add JVM parameters to Apache Kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jaas

When configuring authentication for kafka, the [document](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation#security_sasl) mentioned that JVM parameters need to be added when starting kafka server. like:

`-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_server_jaas.conf`

Since we are using bin/kafka-server-start.sh to start the server, the document didn't mention where to specify the JVM parameters.

Modifying the kafka-server-start.sh or kafka-server-class.sh is not a good idea, then what will be the right way to add the parameter at the start?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'd recommend to use the `KAFKA_OPTS` environment variable for this.

This environment variable is recognized by Kafka, and defaults to the empty string (= no settings).  See the following code snippet from [bin/kafka-run-class.sh](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/aad93840668ae895fce5762c2491b09c32bc3e0c/bin/kafka-run-class.sh#L176-L179) in the Kafka source code:

```
# Generic jvm settings you want to add
if [ -z "$KAFKA_OPTS" ]; then
  KAFKA_OPTS=""
fi
```

So, for example, you can do:

```
$ export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_server_jaas.conf"
$ bin/kafka-server-start.sh
```

or

```
$ KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_server_jaas.conf" bin/kafka-server-start.sh
```

Comment: How do we handle this for application written in python ? How to pass krb5.conf and jaas.conf properties in such case ?

Comment: Please open a separate question for this, as it is off-topic for this one.